# Want to create a cloud sql instance with private and public ip on a separate vpc in gcp using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

I tried to configure a cloud sql instance with private and public ip both in separate vpc using terraform. Can able to assign private ip on that instance from separate vpc but unable to assign public ip along with that.

Here is my code.

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  provider = google-beta

  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = "${var.vpc_self_link}"
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  provider = google-beta

  network                 = "${var.vpc_self_link}"
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}


# create database instance
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
        name = "test-${var.project_id}"
        region = "us-central1"
        database_version = "${var.db_version}"

        depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]

        settings {
                tier = "${var.db_tier}"
                activation_policy = "${var.db_activation_policy}"
                disk_autoresize = "${var.db_disk_autoresize}"
                disk_size = "${var.db_disk_size}"
                disk_type = "${var.db_disk_type}"
                pricing_plan = "${var.db_pricing_plan}"

                database_flags {
                        name  = "slow_query_log"
                        value = "on"
                }

                ip_configuration {
                        ipv4_enabled = "false"
                        private_network = "projects/${var.project_id}/global/networks/${var.vpc_name}"
                }
        }
}
```

but when I try to pass below parameter - to assign public ip, it gives error because of private_network flag .

```
ipv4_enabled = "true"
```

Please let me know how to figure out the issue with private and public ip from custom or separate vpc (not the **default** one).

Answer (score 1):

the question is old, a lot of updates have been done, and you probably solved it by then, nonetheless just wanted to confirm that below is working having both public and private IP, and working in both scenarios of creating the resources from scratch, or modifying an existing instance previously using only public ip.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }

  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "<BUCKET>"
    prefix  = "<PREFIX>"
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}


### VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "private_network" {
  name                    = "private-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.private_network.id
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  network                 = google_compute_network.private_network.id
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}


### INSTANCE
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
  name             = "<INSTANCE>"
  region           = var.region
  database_version = "MYSQL_5_7"

  depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"

    ip_configuration {
        ipv4_enabled    = true
        private_network = google_compute_network.private_network.id

        authorized_networks {
          name = "default"
          value = "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      }
  }
}


### DATABASE
resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  name     = "tf-db"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
}


### USER
resource "google_sql_user" "users" {
  name     = var.sql_user
  password = var.sql_pw
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According with [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html), you can't

> ipv4_enabled - (Optional) Whether this Cloud SQL instance should be assigned a public IPV4 address. Either ipv4_enabled must be enabled or a private_network must be configured.

Open a feature request.